# How to filter an advanced data grid view after a specific row index?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I have an advanced data grid view which is NameTable. Here while using filter option in advanced Datagrid view, first two rows should not get filtered or sorted. Filter option should be applicable after 2nd row only.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public DtTable As DataTable
    Private SBind As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DtTable = New DataTable
        With DtTable
            .Columns.Add(" Name", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Age" + vbLf + " (kg/hr)", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Subject ", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add(" Marks")
        End With
        Dim dr As DataRow
        For i = 0 To 1
            dr = DtTable.NewRow()
            dr(0) = vbNullString
            dr(1) = vbNullString
            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    dr(2) = "Maths"
                Case 1
                    dr(2) = "Science "
            End Select
            DtTable.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        dr = DtTable.NewRow()
        dr(0) = "Mark"
        dr(1) = "18"
        dr(2) = vbNullString
        dr(3) = "98"
        DtTable.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = DtTable.NewRow()
        dr(0) = "Rachel"
        dr(1) = "18"
        dr(2) = vbNullString
        dr(3) = "60"
        DtTable.Rows.Add(dr)

        SBind.DataSource = DtTable
        DataGridView1.DataSource = SBind

    End Sub
 Private Sub IPFSourceADGV_SortStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IPFSourceADGV.SortStringChanged

        Me.SBind.Sort = Me.IPFSourceADGV.SortString
    End Sub
     Private Sub datagridview1_SortStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles datagridview1.SortStringChanged

        Me.SBind.Sort = Me.datagridview1.SortString
    End Sub

    Private Sub datagridview1_FilterStringChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles datagridview1.FilterStringChanged
        Me.SBind.Filter = Me.datagridview1.FilterString
    End Sub

End Class
```

[SampleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGCfe.png)

This just filtering entire table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim DtTable As DataTable = New DataTable

With DtTable
    .Columns.Add(" Name", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("Age" + vbLf + " (kg/hr)", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("Subject ", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add(" Marks")
End With

For Each row As DataRow In DtTable.Rows
    If DtTable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        If DtTable.Rows.IndexOf(row) > 2 Then
            ' filter
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I don't know if i have understood correctly...

With this you can work after the second row of a table. Tell me.